# Guidelines on how to write codes to effectively use ProGuard/ DexGuard?

Tags: java, android, proguard

Are there any guidelines on how to effectively utilize ProGuard/ DexGuard when writing codes? I've read from somewhere that it is good to put away all your sensitive data in a different class instead of putting it inside the `Activity` class itself since `Activity` classes cannot be obfuscated. How can I code my application in such a way that I can maximize my use on ProGuard/ DexGuard? Are there any rules when coding if you're planning to use ProGuard/ DexGuard to avoid application breakage?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right.

Put all "secret" code in obfuscated methods, and let the public methods onyl call
an obfuscted one:

**Example**

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SecretKnowHowWorker.doWork(args);
 }
```

`main` cannot or should not obfuscated, but the rest will be obfuscated.
In Eclipse you can click on "Referenced Librraies" when you click on the obfuscated jar file, you what got obfucated and what not.

Answer (score 1):

Activity class can be perfectly obfuscated however some methods' name (like `onCreate()` for example cannot). So put your sensitive stuff **outside** such entry points like known mehods (all these you want framework to call) and it should be better. I also recomend trying to crack your own app to see how it looks after decoding and put some efforts to make it look worse :)

Comment: Thank you! Aside from it, are there any pointers that I need to take note of? (For example, onClick listeners declared on XML should be excluded from obfuscation because ProGuard is not capable of detecting the relationship between the names declared in the XML files and the names declared in the Java files.)